# Checking to see if a word exist inside of a row in my mysql database with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, exists

So i am trying to allow users to add friends and i am storing all of there friends inside of a single row of the database here is the code i am using

```
socket.on('addFreind', function(username, freind) {

    console.log("ADD FREIND " + freind + " TO " + username)


    connection.query("UPDATE users SET freinds = CONCAT(freinds,'' ' " + freind + "') WHERE username = ?", [username], function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

it will add the friends just fine but even if there is already a friend with the name of nik it will still allow you to add him

i tried this to check if the user already existed in the row but nothing happened

```
    if (connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR(freinds, '" + freind + "'") > 0) {
        console.log("something")
    }
```

what can i do to fix this

Comment: Fix the single quotes.  You don't use them for table or column names.

Comment: i did it didnt fix it

Comment: Why don't you use LIKE to check the friend is exist or not
SELECT * FROM users WHERE freinds LIKE  '% freind %